# How do you set up npm (node package manager) without root access?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Setting npm up as the root user is straighforward and workds. Except you have to run npm commands as root (not recommended). So I thought I'd try setting it up as a non-root user.

According to npm documentation, a non-root user without root access can set up npm by:

1. creating a `.npmrc` file with `root`, `binroot`, and `manroot` pointing to folders that the user owns.
2. Then running the install script.

OK. Install was fine.

But node can't see the packages provided by npm.

So how do I make node aware of the packages provided by npm? (I didn't have to do anything when I previously installed npm as root). 
I can set `require.paths` within node, or set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable, but to what?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't npm come with node now? I've never had to run npm commans as root unless I'm using -g...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through a little exploration, it seems you can either:

1. set your `NODE_PATH` to whatever npm's root directory is, or
2. while in node, invoke `require.paths.push('path_to_npm_root')`

Comment: And if you're trying to debug this from the repl, see http://github.com/ry/node/issues/closed#issue/303

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

1. Make a `~/.node` folder

   ```
   mkdir ~/.node
   ```
2. Edit `~/.npmrc` and add the line

   ```
   prefix = ~/.node
   ```
3. Edit your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` and add these lines

   ```
   PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
   NODE_PATH="$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
   ```

Now I can do things like `npm -g install http-server` and it will install to `~/.node` without root. With this in place, when I then type `http-server`, it runs.