# Basic WebGl / Javascript configuration

Tags: javascript, three.js

On OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks) working on WebGL tutorial script from http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene where I copied and pasted the code from this first tutorial into TextEdit and saved it as HTML:

webgl
    |
    +--index.html
    |
    +-- js/three.min.js

Why when I load the index.html into the browser do I not see the expected result of a WebGl rendered cube, but rather I see the HMTL code rendered just like in my text editor?  Thank you.

Comment: Speculation: You are writing your HTML in a WYSIWYG editor which is saving an HTML document designed to show the source code you are typing in. If so, use a text editor and not a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: I'm using a text editor. TextEdit.  I finally sorted nodejs server install and start on both laptop and desktop, but still seeing HTML rather than the WebGL cube rendered.  Completely stumped.

Comment: TextEdit, despite it's name, is a WYSIWYG word processor, not a text editor. You can tell because it has a toolbar full of buttons like Bold and Right Align which modify the appearance of what you see and don't just insert tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do three.js development you should run a simple web server. It's super easy and will take just a moment to setup.

Windows steps:

> 1. Install node.js [from here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
> 2. Open a Node.js command prompt.
> 3. Type `npm install -g http-server`

On OSX/Linux

> 1. Install node.js [from here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
> 2. Open a terminal / shell.
> 3. Type `sudo npm install -g http-server`

Now cd to the folder of your files and type `http-server`. Example

```
cd "myproject"
http-server
```

Now in your browser to go to `http://localhost:8080` or `http://localhost:8080/nameoffile.html`

Otherwise your issue is likely your path to `three.min.js` is wrong? If your setup is like this

```
myproject
|
+--index.html
|
+--js
   |
   +--three.min.js
```

Then inside your `index.html` your script tag should look like this

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no need for web server for three.js development. It works offline (except the textures with some browsers).

Comment: You should use a webserver because you're most likely going to need images and you can't read images from file: except by turning off security in your browser which is about the stupidest thing you could possibly do.

Comment: Of course you are right (although textures work offline on Windows IE and FF with default settings). But the issue here that the html itself does not render in the browser, the asker see only the html source. I think it is not a server issue. Maybe he really named his file as HMTL and it is not a typos.

Comment: @gman Bkgd: I've an OSX computer, have named index.html, did place three.min.js inside of js dir and have the exact tutorial script from http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene  Installed node.js pkg v4.1.1.  then checked, the $PATH - all good there. Received this error after submitting  'KPR$ sudo npm install -g http-server sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting' ,  so sort of stuck on that now. Any help and insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've researched 'sudo' and the 'sudoers' file and now trying to create a valid sudoers file at the appropriate location.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error but you can do it without `sudo` [if you follow these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32829579/128511)

Comment: The code and files are in the correct directories on this laptop, but getting the server to install and started is moving off topic, as I confirmed the suderos file a.) exists and b.) is in the correct directory etc/sudoers . I've move to my Desktop (10.10.x Yosemite) where the server install and server start have worked, though the HTML is still rendering in the browser. Anyway it seems best to close this here and it move to Apple.StackExchange.com .  @gman I'll try you suggestion on this Laptop (10.9.5 Mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a text editor. TextEdit.

TextEdit is a WYSIWYG word processor, not a text editor. It has an unfortunate name.

When you type this:

[image: TextEdit]

And save it like this:

[image: Save As]

You get this (an HTML document designed to display what you typed instead of treating what you typed as HTML source code):

[image: Plain text content of the file]

You need to use a real text editor such as:

- Sublime Text
- Brackets
- Vim
- Komodo Edit

Comment: Thats interesting cause after gettting a working configuration = nodejs install and sudo permissions fixed, editing with TextEdit of the HMTL file on my laptop (OSX 10.9.5 Mavericks) it is working and active responding to text edits. However, on my desktop (OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite) with the exact same configuration (server running, but I didn't run the same permissions fix as it wasn't required),  I've yet to see the webGl cube when the index.html file is loaded.